# converting http directory listing into a dataframe and access path in each row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, urllib

I am able to access an http url and retrieve the directory listing. Then i go line by line and check if each url has a `.txt` extension and accessing it using `requests.content` and decode the txt file.
However I want to be able to filter the listing based on the date. The directory listing is like so:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>IP Address/Log</TITLE>
<BODY>
<H1>Log</H1><HR>

<PRE><A HREF="/Main/">[To Parent Directory]</A>
  23/11/18    19:07          314 <A HREF="/Log/Alarm_231118.txt">Alarm_231118.txt</A>
  23/11/16    23:59       150516 <A HREF="/Log/Temperature%20Detail_Data%20Log_231116.txt">Temperature Detail_Data Log_231116.txt</A>
  23/11/28    15:22          450 <A HREF="/Log/Alarm_231128.txt">Alarm_231128.txt</A>
  23/11/17     0:00       450536 <A HREF="/Log/Temperature%20Detail_Data%20Log.log">Temperature Detail_Data Log.log</A>
  23/11/16    23:59       110148 <A HREF="/Log/Water%20Temp%20Trend_Data%20Log_231116.txt">Water Temp Trend_Data Log_231116.txt</A>
</PRE><HR></BODY></HTML>
```

Im only interested in the rows that have the data, time size and the HREF link. I want to create a dataframe where the first column is the date, second is the time, third is the size and the 4th is the link.
To access each link i use the following code:

```
for line in lines:
    if ".txt" in line:
        filename = line.split('"')[1]
        if filename.startswith(file_prefix_all) and filename.endswith(".txt"):
             file_url = url_root + filename
             print(file_url)
             file_response = requests.get(file_url, auth=auth)
             if file_response.status_code == 200:
                # Read the CSV content into a Pandas DataFrame
                file_content = file_response.content.decode('utf-8')
                df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_content), encoding='utf-8', sep='\t')
                files_dataframes.append(df)
```

Will I be able to use the same method once i get the listing into a dataframe?
Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps something like `df['link'].str.extract(r'"([^"]+)')` to get the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to parse the text, for example:

```py
import re

import pandas as pd

text = """\
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>IP Address/Log</TITLE>
<BODY>
<H1>Log</H1><HR>

<PRE><A HREF="/Main/">[To Parent Directory]</A>
  23/11/18    19:07          314 <A HREF="/Log/Alarm_231118.txt">Alarm_231118.txt</A>
  23/11/16    23:59       150516 <A HREF="/Log/Temperature%20Detail_Data%20Log_231116.txt">Temperature Detail_Data Log_231116.txt</A>
  23/11/28    15:22          450 <A HREF="/Log/Alarm_231128.txt">Alarm_231128.txt</A>
  23/11/17     0:00       450536 <A HREF="/Log/Temperature%20Detail_Data%20Log.log">Temperature Detail_Data Log.log</A>
  23/11/16    23:59       110148 <A HREF="/Log/Water%20Temp%20Trend_Data%20Log_231116.txt">Water Temp Trend_Data Log_231116.txt</A>
</PRE><HR></BODY></HTML>"""


df = pd.DataFrame(
    map(
        re.Match.groupdict,
        re.finditer(
            r'(?P<date>\d+/\d+/\d+).*?(?P<time>\d+:\d+).*?(?P<size>\d+).*?HREF="(?P<filename>[^"]+)"',
            text,
        ),
    )
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       date   time    size                                         filename
0  23/11/18  19:07     314                            /Log/Alarm_231118.txt
1  23/11/16  23:59  150516  /Log/Temperature%20Detail_Data%20Log_231116.txt
2  23/11/28  15:22     450                            /Log/Alarm_231128.txt
3  23/11/17   0:00  450536         /Log/Temperature%20Detail_Data%20Log.log
4  23/11/16  23:59  110148  /Log/Water%20Temp%20Trend_Data%20Log_231116.txt
```

---

Then to filter the dataframe:

```py
print(df[df.filename.str.endswith(".txt")])
```

Prints:

```
       date   time    size                                         filename
0  23/11/18  19:07     314                            /Log/Alarm_231118.txt
1  23/11/16  23:59  150516  /Log/Temperature%20Detail_Data%20Log_231116.txt
2  23/11/28  15:22     450                            /Log/Alarm_231128.txt
4  23/11/16  23:59  110148  /Log/Water%20Temp%20Trend_Data%20Log_231116.txt
```

Comment: When i try your method i get the following error: `expected string or bytes-like object, got 'list'`. In my code, the list `lines` essentially has the content of `text` in your solution. When i print `lines` it outputs a long string like so: `['<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>IP Address</TITLE>', '<BODY>', '<H1>Log</H1><HR>', '', '<PRE><A HREF="/Main/">[To Parent Directory]</A>', '  23/11/18    19:07   314 <A HREF="Log/Alarm_231118.txt">Alarm_231118.txt</A>',...`

Comment: @thentangler Pass the whole response (string) to `re.finditer`, not list

Comment: Thank You! That worked! For the `re.finditer` expression, do we need to define where to fine the various columns? So like 3 spaces for the `time`, 6 spaces for the `size` and to extract string after `HREF=` for the `filename`?

Comment: @thentangler That's not needed, the `.*?` consumes variable number of characters. You can play with the regex for example here: https://regex101.com/r/jWCg5n/1